# Get value from another dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
>>> df1
           a   b
0  [1, 2, 3]  10
1  [4, 5, 6]  20
2     [7, 8]  30
```

and another like:

```
>>> df2
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

I need to create column 'c' in df2 from column 'b' of df1 if column 'a' value of df2 is in coulmn 'a' df1. In df1 each tuple of column 'a' is a list.

I have tried to implement from following url, but got nothing so far:
https://medium.com/@Imaadmkhan1/using-pandas-to-create-a-conditional-column-by-selecting-multiple-columns-in-two-different-b50886fabb7d

expect result is

```
>>> df2
   a  c
0  1 10
1  2 10
2  3 10
3  4 20
4  5 20
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by flattening values from `df1` to dictionary:

```
d = {c: b for a, b in zip(df1['a'], df1['b']) for c in a}
print (d)
{1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 20, 5: 20, 6: 20, 7: 30, 8: 30}

df2['new'] = df2['a'].map(d)
print (df2)
   a  new
0  1   10
1  2   10
2  3   10
3  4   20
4  5   20
```

EDIT: I think problem is mixed integers in list in column `a`, solution is use if/else for test it for new dictionary:

```
d = {}
for a, b in zip(df1['a'], df1['b']):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        for c in a:
            d[c] = b
    else:
        d[a] = b

df2['new'] = df2['a'].map(d)
```

Comment: Actual data is a list of ip. I am getting the below error, there:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @BinayakChatterjee - Data are confidental?

Comment: @BinayakChatterjee - Is possible edit question? Because bad formating of comments data. Thank you.

Comment: @BinayakChatterjee - so change `d = {c: b for a, b in zip(df1['a'], df1['b']) for c in a}` to `d = {c: b for a, b in zip(df1['b'], df1['a']) for c in a}` - swap a, b

Answer (score 4):

Use :

```
m=pd.DataFrame({'a':np.concatenate(df.a.values),'b':df.b.repeat(df.a.str.len())})
df2.merge(m,on='a')
```

---

```
   a   b
0  1  10
1  2  10
2  3  10
3  4  20
4  5  20
```

Answer (score 2):

First we `unnest` the list df1 to rows, then we merge them on column `a`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('b').a.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'a'})
print(df1, '\n')

df_final = df2.merge(df1, on='a')
print(df_final)

    b    a
0  10  1.0
1  10  2.0
2  10  3.0
0  20  4.0
1  20  5.0
2  20  6.0
0  30  7.0
1  30  8.0 

   a   b
0  1  10
1  2  10
2  3  10
3  4  20
4  5  20
```

Comment: Thanks for heads up @jezrael. I use this method from Wen-Bens post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939

Comment: Ya, unfortunately is still used a lot, but the best never used it - to slow.

Comment: Maybe you should post an answer, eplaining this dict flattening you use? @jezrael